# Mobilefirst 8.0 and scheduled tasks (similar to Quartz)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I'm using MobileFirst 8.0 in my project and I'd like to add some interesting use cases... Anybody knows if there are any options to schedule tasks in MobileFirst?

I have experience with Quartz library. Is there something similar to it? Or something that the MobileFirst server provides for this purpose?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom tasks cannot be scheduled in MobileFirst 8.0.

You can, however, have schedulers or jobs running outside of MFP, that invokes MFP REST endpoints to execute some task/job periodically.

List of MFP REST endpoints:

[REST API for the MobileFirst Server administration service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/c_restapi_oview.html)

[REST API for the MobileFirst Server push service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/c_restapi_runtime.html)

[REST API for the MobileFirst runtime](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/c_restapi_runtime_overview.html)

Comment: Although it is not the answer I was expecting, it is covering the question I asked. So, this is the correct answer, Thanks @Vivin!